# Full Screen image slider with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have to make a demo website somewhat similar to http://issuu.com/eb_magazine/docs/ebmag_31/1. The website is coded in flash but I want to do it using javascript and jQuery.
I think I need to do this in two parts, first is a simple image slider to slides between images. I think I can use any jQuery Image slider plugin for that.
The second part where we click on the image and it opens in full screen image slider with a zoom option. I don't know which plugin can be used for that. Is that even possible to do with jQuery? Please suggest any plugins for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think http://www.turnjs.com/ is the best solution for your query.

> Turn.js is a JavaScript library that will make your content look like
>   a real book or magazine using all the advantages of HTML5. The web is
>   getting beautiful with new user interfaces based in HTML5; turn.js is
>   the best fit for a magazine, book or catalog based in HTML5.

Here's a sample code:

```
<div id="flipbook">
    <div class="hard"> Turn.js </div> 
    <div class="hard"></div>
    <div> Page 1 </div>
    <div> Page 2 </div>
    <div> Page 3 </div>
    <div> Page 4 </div>
    <div class="hard"></div>
    <div class="hard"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#flipbook").turn({
        width: 400,
        height: 300,
        autoCenter: true
    });
</script>
```